# Adding subtraction to RPG dice discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am building a bot that can calculate multiple dice rolls at once, as of right now, i can add multiple dices and fixed numbers, but to subtract, the syntax looks like this: #roll 1d20+-1d6, i have been trying to just be able to type the "-" sign, but i can't find a way to do it. Code below.

```
@bot.command(name="roll")
async def roll(ctx, dices: str):
    l_dices = dices.split("+")
    length = len(l_dices)
    values = []
    total = 0
    valueString = ""

    #loops through every dice/modifier
    for x in l_dices:
        #checks if it is a dice or modifier value
        if "d" in x:
            #splits between number of dices and number of sides in each dice
            number = int(x.split("d")[0])
            sides = int(x.split("d")[1])
            for i in range(number):
                #gets a random value in the range of the dice
                dice_result = random.randrange(1, sides + 1)
                values.append(dice_result)
                
                #adds every die to a list to show individual dice results
                if valueString == '':
                    valueString += str(dice_result)
                else:
                    valueString += ', ' + str(dice_result)
        else:
            #adds together every modifier
            total += int(x)
    #gets the final result
    total += sum(values)
    #show the final results in chat
    await ctx.send(ctx.message.author.mention + "\n:VALORES:\n" + valueString + "\n:RESULTADO:\n" + str(total))
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Not sure what exactly it is you want to do/happen with the code (don't know anything about rpg dice to be fair).

Comment: just want to be able to make straight subtractions. Right now to subtract a number i need to write it like (5+-3)

Comment: But what would the answer be? I don't know what it's supposed to do. You are getting the different dice with `split('+')` so at least that would have to change for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that currently you're using a "+" as your separator, as you defined in:

```
l_dices = dices.split("+")
```

This means, that you're only separating the parts of the command via the "+" signs, nothing else. So in order to fix this, you need to fix how you parse your user input. I would personally recommend using regex, as that will allow you to add more separators quite easily in the future. Here's a quick code snippet that parses your commands by both a + and - sign:

```py
import re
def parsecommand(command_string):
    commands = re.split(r"(\+|\-)",command_string)
    return commands
```

This will parse the command string, splitting either by + or -, and will add also output the signs. For example:

```py
>>>commandstr = "d6+d8-2d12"
>>>print(parsecommand(commandstr))
["d6","+","d8","-","2d12"]
```

And I'm sure you can from there easily parse this list to run whatever calculations you want :)